# How to make cards adjust position vertically?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, frontend

I'd like my cards to fit the empty space vertically, I don't care if they are not aligned with the cards of the other column. How can I do this.
Current code:

```
<template>
<vs-row vs-type="flex" >
  <vs-col vs-col:key="index" v-for="ransom in info"  vs-w="6" >
  <vx-card>
      <div>
      <p>some text of various size<p>
      </div>
        <div slot="footer">
          <vs-row vs-justify="flex-end">
            <vs-button color="primary" type="gradient" >View</vs-button>
            <vs-button color="danger" type="gradient" >Delete</vs-button>
          </vs-row>
        </div>
  </vx-card>
  </vs-col>
</vs-row>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto?

Comment: That will make for example the card on top left center to the one on the right and there will be spaces on top and bottom